# Не удается запустить код при подключении метода template.parseFiles почему ошибка?

Tags: golang, шаблоны

```
package main

import ("fmt"
        "net/http"
        "html/template")


type User struct {
     name   string
     age    uint16
     money  int16
     avg_grades,heppiness float64
} 
func (u User) getAllInfo() string {

    return fmt.Sprintf("User name is: %s.He is %d he has is money %d ",u.name,u.age,u.money)
}

func (u *User) setNewName(newName string) {
    u.name = newName
}

func home_page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    bob := User {"Bob",25,-50,4.2,0.8}
    //bob.setNewName("Alex")
    //fmt.Fprintf(w, bob.getAllInfo())

    tmpl, _ := template.parseFiles("templates/home_page.html")
    tmpl.Execute(w, bob)
} 

func contacts_page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){

        fmt.Fprintf(w,"Contacts page")
    } 

func hanlde_request(){

     http.HandleFunc("/", home_page)
     http.HandleFunc("/contacts/", contacts_page)
     http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil)
  
}     

func main()  {
    //bob := User {name: "Bob",age:25, money: -50 avg_grades:4.2,heppiness:0.8}
        
     hanlde_request()

}        
===========================================================================================
Вывод в браузер через метод Fprintf работает, а через template.parseFiles ошибка.  
===========================================================================================
go версия 1.17.8 windows 7 процессор amd
===========================================================================================
ошибка при запуске
.\main.go:27:35: not enough arguments in call to "html/template".parseFiles
        have (string)
        want (*"html/template".Template, func(string) (string, []byte, error), ...string)
```

Comment: А перевести ошибку и осмыслить её - не?

Comment: Это понятно , что не достаточно аргументов чтобы вызвать "html/template" , a вот и за чего не понятно.

Comment: Из-за того что вы не выполнили условие, добавив необходимые аргументы при вызове функции parseFiles. Сравнивая текущий [package](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template#ParseFiles) и ваш, видно что они различаются, Какой package вы используете и какой версии?

Comment: package все родные которые шли с go версия 1.17.8 , нечего не добавлял переменные окружения системные path = c:\go\bin пользователя GOPATCH = c:\users\user\go

Comment: Считаю вам нужно использовать ParseFiles вместо приватной parseFiles в этом package.

Comment: Да. все верно. теперь работает. спасибо.